# How to add Yii CDN Asset Management?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions, yii2-basic-app

I am trying to use this extension https://github.com/2amigos/yii-cdn-asset-management-library in order to publish my assets to Amazon S3.

I am using yii2 advanced application 
I have already added my upload images section to the do bucket with these configuration.

```
    $uploader = new FileUpload(FileUpload::S_S3, [
        'version'  => Yii::$app->params['do_version'],
        'region'   => Yii::$app->params['do_region'],
        'endpoint' => Yii::$app->params['do_endpoint'],

        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => Yii::$app->params['do_key'],
            'secret' => Yii::$app->params['do_secret'],
        ],
        'bucket'      => Yii::$app->params['do_bucket'],
    ]);
    $uploader->setUploadFolder($folder);
    //$uploader = $model->photo;
    return $uploader->uploadFromFile($photo)->path;
```

Can any one guide me properly that how i can add my assets via cdn go bucket  which i have configured in `backend/assets/Appassets.php` like this

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
        'css/styles.css',
        'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100,500,700,900',
        'css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'css/core.min.css',
        'css/components.css',
        'css/colors.min.css',
        '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/app.js',
        'js/custom.js',
        'js/bootstrap.min.js',
        'js/pace.min.js',
        // 'js/tagsinput.min.js',
        'js/tokenfield.min.js',
        'js/form_tags_input.js',
        //'js/datepicker.js',
        // 'js/jquery.min.js',



    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
        // 'bedezign\yii2\audit\web\JSLoggingAsset',
    ];
}
```

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Have a look please i am sure you have already worked on this